# Apache php 5.3 postgreSQL driver could not be loaded

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, pdo

I have set up a XAMPP installation on a windows server 2008 R2 that includes:

- Apache 2
- PHP 5.3.x
- MySQL (not used anyway)

Then I have installed PostGreSQL 9.x. I have uncommented the pgsql pdo dlls in the php.ini file accordingly but when I try to connect to pgsql I get 'driver could not be loaded'. I am stuck as I couldn't come across a fix to that on the internet, I have tried adding the path of the pgsql installation (bin and lib dirs) to the PATH environement system but the problem persists. I have also rebooted the system many times after changing any configuration to ensure it is saved and applied but still same outcome.

I have read in a nonclear conversation that this might be related to the versions but couldn't find anything further.

If you have succeeded in performing the latter I would be greateful if you could provide me with some insight. (I am open to any alternatives except downgrading to older software versions).

Thanks so much for your time

Comment: Does phpinfo list support for pdo including support for postgresql? If so then please post your code.

Comment: What have you done so far to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you loaded the module for Postgre?

Comment: @Eelke: phpinfo does not show that pdo for pgsql is loaded actually. So it's not a problem in the code. hakre: I googled :) then I copied the DLLs in the windows system dir (found that hint on the internet) also set up the PATH env. variable. Shane: As I am saying it appears that it's not loaded for a reason I ignore. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by manually installing apache2 and php instead of going through xampp (or wampp). It seems those are buggy when it comes to the latest php version and pgsql pdo driver.