# Not able to connect PostgreSQL with Yii

Tags: postgresql, yii

I have tried to connect PostgreSQL with Yii but is is showing

CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.

In log it is showing

```
error   exception.CDbException
```

could not find driver

My code

```
'db'=>array(
    'tablePrefix'=>'',
    'connectionString' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=postgres',
    'username'=>'postgres',
    'password'=>'postgres',
    'charset'=>'UTF8',
),
```

Comment: do you try connect via console app?

Comment: Are you certain the connection is working? Maybe try a "plain" PHP connection and see if that works first

Comment: tried everything but it is not working....is there anything to be edited in apache httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved issue...by adding

```
LoadFile "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/libpq.dll"
```

to httpd.conf file. Now phpinfo() is showing pgsql PDO.

thanks...

Comment: That is bad way actually. Any upgrade that will overwrite config will result in need for you to re-write config file. If you read my first link on windows there is better way there. You *should* have followed that and accepted my answer :) here I quote 

"The PHP extension will look for libpq.dll which is found of your PostgreSQL installation. The simple fix is to add the path than contains that file to your environment PATH. Here is the steps I’ve taken."

Comment: so Just add C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ to your system path variable restart your machine (if necessary) and you are done!

Answer (score 2):

Yii Database component is build on top of PHP PDO. So Here are list of posibilities to check

Check that PostgreSQL and PostgreSQL's PDO Extension is installed and working. Also that port is right one. You can test simple [PHP Script to test](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php#97699).

Below are links to something that might be similar

[PostgreSql 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085039/postgresql-pdoexception-with-message-could-not-find-driver)

[PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

**Install PDO on Linux (Ubuntu/Debian)**

[Install pdo for postgres Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180869/install-pdo-for-postgres-ubuntu)

https://serverfault.com/questions/89970/how-to-install-postgresql-extension-for-pdo-in-linux

**Windows**

http://blog.lysender.com/2010/08/php-and-postgresql-on-windows/

[Apache php 5.3 postgreSQL driver could not be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083377/apache-php-5-3-postgresql-driver-could-not-be-loaded)

**Official PHP Information on Issue**

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php

Comment: in my phpinfo()...the pdo support is not enabled for postgressql..it is there for mysql and sqlite. how can i fix this

Comment: thank you for all these links....tried everything but the issue was resolved by following step...

Answer (score 1):

if you work in ubuntu make sure that you have installed pgsql library

```
sudo apt-get install php-pgsql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

after make sure that in the console and main-local there are this array

```
'components' => [
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=yourdb',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pw',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],],
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a case of enabling the `php_pdo_pgsql` extension in WAMP

Answer (score 0):

for those struggling with the same issue i did the work around.
environment
Yii2
server:LAMP stack 7.1
problem Driver not found i.e the "requirements.php" shows warning
"PDO PostgreSQL extension   Warning All DB-related classes  Required for PostgreSQL database."
i noted that pdo_pgsql.so is not packaged together with bitnami so i search for it online  or try locate if installed on any php versions in /usr/lib/php

1. copy that file to lampstack-7.1.10-1/php/lib/php/extensions.
2. now go to lampstack php.ini "lampstack-7.1.10-1/php/etc/php.ini"
   now place this line "extension=pdo_pgsql.so" remove ; if commented out NB you can point to the absolute path "/usr/lib/php/pdo_pgsql.so" if it existed there
3. restart Lamp apache server
4. visit requirement.php and if you see ""PDO PostgreSQL extension  **Passed**  All DB-related classes  Required for PostgreSQL database.""